# Does the use of 'Christ Jesus' have any special significance?

Tags: jesus

In some places, Jesus is referred to as 'Jesus Christ', whereas in others He is referred to as 'Christ Jesus'. Is there any special significance to this?

Comment: Christ Jesus, rather underlines his Messianic role. As Christ means the Anointed or the Messiah (in Greek). Whilst Jesus Christ is used to refer more to his human nature, as Jesus is His name given to Him in his birth, here.